# Copy char * allocated with malloc to std::string

Tags: c++, string

Hi I'm trying to **copy** `char *` to `std::string`, the `char *` variable allocated with `malloc`, after the copy I want to free `char *` cause I'm pretty sure `std::string` won't free it. I want to do that without affecting the newly created `std::string`.

```
typedef struct {
  std::string name;
} st;

st fst;
name = (char *) malloc(len + 1);
for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
    name[i] = name_orig[offset + i]; //name_orig is const unsigned char *
name[i] = 0;

fst.name.assign(name,len);
free(name);
cout << fst.name << endl; // prints "wiped"
```

Comment: Please tell me why you are using `malloc` and also casting it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? C++ compilers **abominate** `malloc`.

Comment: And use braces for the `for` loop;

Comment: Do not add C tag for non-C code!

Comment: @Olaf its C/C++ code!

Comment: @Ed Heal, about malloc, I think I get a warning if I don't do that, and about for loop, I like it better without it.

Comment: Please try it - you should not - also do not use it in C++ code

Comment: @EdHeal C++ does not implicitly cast out of `void*`, so the cast is necessary.

Comment: Another good reason not to use `malloc` in C++ code

Comment: What is C/C++ code, please? I know C and C++. What is C/C++? If you have a compiler at handy I'l be glad if you can hand it over.

Comment: In C++, you should use `name = new char[len+1]` and `delete[] name`, and you should use `memcpy` or `std::copy` to copy the string.  But all of this is totally unnecessary since you can assign `&name_orig[offset]` directly to the `std::string`.

Comment: @Koten Try not to mix c and c++ together .... it just make things worse ...
what is the problem in your above code .. the snippet looks fine .. Is not free(name) freeing the char* ?

Comment: @Ajay, It is freeing `char *`, but I think `std::string` uses the `char *` so it also affected the `std::string`,so when I free the `char *` and print the std::string "wiped" gets printed and not the contents of the deleted `char *`

Comment: @Ajay, my bad, you are correct.

Comment: The `assign` method copies the contents of the C-string into the `std::string`, so it doesn't matter what happens to the C-string after that.  The `std::string` will be independent of it.

Comment: Please provide a link to the definition of that "C/C++" language. If you do, I will happily define a corresponding tag, because there are many people whou refer to this language. As far as I know, there are the two **different** languages C and C++. The code above does not compile with a C compiler and vilotates the C standard, so it is definitively not C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `malloc`'d string and the copy are unnecessary.  You can just do

```
typedef struct {
  std::string name;
} st;

st fst;

fst.name.assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&name_orig[offset]), len);
```

Comment: name_orig is const unsigned char *, sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: Then if you're OK with coercing the unsigned chars into chars, then you can just cast `&name_orig[offset]` to `const char*` with `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&name_orig[offset])`.  But why are you trying to create a `std::string` out of unsigned chars?